# Save zip file with filename as name of files zipped

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I have made a linux script to zip a set of pcap files in a folder. It saves the files older than 2 days to a zip files. the zip is saved with current time and date as the file name for the zip. Is there anyway to use the first and last pcap file as the file name for zip file.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/md0/capture/DCN
#Limit of your choice
ulimit -s 32000
LIMIT=10
#Get the number of files, that has `*.pcap`
in its name, with last modified time 5 days      ago
NUMBER=$(find /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" -mtime +5 | wc -l)
if [[ $NUMBER -gt $LIMIT ]]  #if number greater than limit
then
FILES=$(find /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" -mtime +5)
#find the files
zip -j /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/capture_zip-$(date "+%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S").zip $FILES
#zip them
rm $FILES
#delete the originals
ulimit -s 8192 #reset the limit
fi #end of if.
```

Comment: What do you mean by first and last? How should the files be ordered?

Comment: Files be ordered by the time of modification..

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use shell arrays:

```
IFS=$'\n' FILES=($(find /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pcap" -mtime +5))
#find the files and put the paths into an array "FILES"
```

This puts all of the files with paths into the shell array "FILES" and takes into consideration blanks in file names. The order will be in whatever order `find` gives them.

To build the zip file name:

```
FIRSTNAME=${FILES[0]##*/}
LASTNAME=${FILES[${#FILES[@]}-1]##*/}
ZIPPREFIX="${FIRSTNAME%.*}-${LASTNAME%.*}"
#zip base name made from first and last file basenames
```

Here, `FIRSTNAME=${FILES[0]##*/}` yields the name of the file with extension, and `${FIRSTNAME%.*}` removes the extension. It will strip off the path and file extension. (If you want to keep the file extension, you can use `$FIRSTNAME`.) The value `${#FILES[@]}` is the number of files in the array. Thus, the somewhat messy-looking `${FILES[${#FILES[@]}-1]}` represents the last file name in the array. And finally the extra little bit of `##*/` in `${FILES[${#FILES[@]}-1]##/*}` removes the path, leaving the file name. Ultimately, `ZIPPREFIX` will be the first base name, a hyphen (`-`), and the last base name. You can use a different character other than hyphen if you wish.

```
zip -j /mnt/md0/capture/dcn/"$ZIPPREFIX"-$(date "+%b_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S").zip "${FILES[@]}"
#zip them
```

This zips the files. Note that `${FILES[@]}` provides all of the array elements.

```
rm "${FILES[@]}"
#remove all the files
```

Comment: Ad some quotes or the script will not work for files with spaces in their names.

Comment: The problem still persists in `FILES=($(...))`.

Comment: @choroba Thanks for catching that. When I initially tried it, I thought it captured the spaces correctly, but I had done something wrong. So it is now updated.